# Concat two variables and pass as an URL to ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a file named domainname.xml and many other html files..
I get the value of 'x' from that file.

Now i need to concatenate 'y' with it and pass as an URL to an ajax call...

Thats my specific need guys !!

```
Var x=http://www.xyzftp/myservice/service1.svc

Var y=/logincheck
```

Now i need to concat these two and pass it as an URL to an ajax call !!!

I have already asked a similar question but i couldnot pass it as an url to ajax call..

**MY TRY :**

```
var x='http://www.xyzftp/myservice/service1.svc';
var y='/logincheck';

var z = x + y;     

 "http://www.xyzftp/myservice/service1.svc/logincheck"



var z = x.concat(y);

"http://www.xyzftp/myservice/service1.svc/logincheck"
```

My problem is i could not pass it as an url to ajax call

Comment: `/!{2,}/.test(question.content) && question.downvote();` Please work on your answer by a) using correct JavaScript examples, b) not using unnecessary tags and c) making an attempt yourself.

Comment: If `z === "http://www.xyzftp/myservice/service1.svc/logincheck"`, why are you not able to "*pass it as an url to ajax call*?" How are you currently attempting to pass it to an ajax call (you've left out that snippet of code and we can't really help with what we can't see)? Does your browser report any errors or warnings in its debugger/console? Also, would this be a [same- or cross-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) request -- is the current page requested from `http://www.xyzftp/` or a different protocol/host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var x="http://www.example.com/";
var y="test/test";
var url=x+y;
```

now put this url on ajax:

Comment: the var x value is not given by me..It is retrieved from the domainname.xml file...so it comes without quotes !!

Comment: @PraveenGodfrey u add it later first put your question in right format and easy to understand. see example of ajax call using jquery if u dont know  ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @PraveenGodfrey r u asking help here or come to say "idiot", just wasting time.

Comment: @PraveenGodfrey: Do you understand what a "string" is? The quotes don't matter at all, unless you’re using `eval`, and you’re not. Right? …right?

Comment: @minitech Can you elaborate on the quotes and `eval()`? Curious

Comment: @PraveenGodfrey It's unacceptable to call users *idiot* here.

Comment: @PraveenGodfrey i have to say ur question does not have enough information to give u a right answer what u r expecting.

Comment: @alex: `eval(x + '+' + y)` *dies a little inside*

Comment: @minitech Would using double quotes there make a difference? I might be misunderstanding what you're getting at.

Comment: @alex: “It is retrieved from the domainname.xml file...so it comes without quotes !!”

Answer (score 0):

include [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and use

```
$.ajax({url: x+y});
```

Comment: dude x and y are without quotes and i should concat them so that the result is within single quotes and then pass it as an url to ajax !!

Comment: @PraveenGodfrey: Yeah, that's… what this does.

Comment: @minitech:I tried it..but no effect..it says "domainname not defined"

Thimk i should declare it as an global variable...any idea on declaring it as a global variable ??

Comment: @PraveenGodfrey: … what is `domainname`? Can you show your full code, please?

Comment: @minitech : Thnk u..
u actually solved it..it does come with quotes..It was very simple..I made it messy..but thnks for clearing my doubts..

since i m a newbie,feel difficult to understand these stuffs !!